# Cleaning polylines

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have polylines that are irregularly overlapping each other (see picture).

[image]

Is there anyway to cleanup them so I can have either transform the 2 lines crosscutting into 1, or keep the 2 lines but without the overlapping?

I tried to play around Subtract and Intersect tools, as well as with Integrate/Planarize but those don't give good results.

Comment: Try dissolve, no multi parts and intrgate

Comment: Also try, Cartography Tools, Generalization, Simplify Line & Smooth Line.

Comment: What do you consider a good result and what about the results of the Subtract, Intersect and Integrate/Planarize approaches did you consider a bad result.  Your end goal is far too subjective for me to imagine what you want without a better definition of what you find acceptable and unacceptable in the final output.

Comment: Thank you klewis, simplifying and smoothing did the trick!